selenium with chrome driver on ubuntu/debian not working properly
i am currently working on a scrping project and i am using selenium with chrome the problem that i found is when the browser opens its not showing anythong and its not navigation to the correct url, i can scrape the data wihout using selenium with chrome  but i whant to see the UI
Code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()
# options.add_argument('--headless')
# options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

driver.get("https://python.org")
print(driver.title)
driver.close()

the interface that i am seeing: its not navigation to the correct url

I'm following this documentation to set up Selenium with Chrome on Ubuntu/Debian.
I think there might be a version mismatch problem on my laptop, possibly related to SM (Shared Memory) or driver compatibility. I tried using time.sleep() and WebDriverWait, but neither worked.
I also switched to Firefox, but encountered a Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 127.
Any ideas on what might be causing this?

did you try this with just option driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options), btw can I know your Ubuntu details? like version, dual boot, or anything, because driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options) just worked perfectly on my Ubuntu
